# ¿Cómo comprobar que un elemento de mi JSON es el primero?

Tags: jquery, json

Necesito comprobar el primer elemento para poder hacer un if.

Ejemplo de JSON:

```
{"elementos": [
          {
              "elemento": [
                  {
                      "hora": "00:00:00.000"
                  },
                  {
                      "hora": "00:00:00.450"
                  }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

Y lo estoy haciendo con un each y debo comprobarlo dentro de este mismo.

```
$.each(json.elementos.elemento, function(index_elementos, valores_elementos){
   /*En el caso que tuviera un elemento llamado hora*/

valores_elementos[0].hora == /*a el primer elemento*/;

)};
```

es un ejemplo burdo pero creo que se entiende.

Comment: ¿Qué deseas lograr?

Comment: El primer elemento es el que tiene índice 0 (que ya lo tienes en tu código). ¿Dónde está el problema?

Comment: Que necesitas comprobar en tu primer elemento? si es una hora? si está vacío? si es nulo? Podrías dar una mejor descripción

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua, estoy recien aprendiendo asi que muchas gracias :D

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ponlo como respuesta